# Is there a way i can intergrate Paystack payments in an ionic3 App

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

i've been trying to implement paystack payments in my ionic 3 app using angular. I used angular4-paystack but it did not work. Please help !!!

Ionic:

Ionic CLI          : 5.4.16
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
Cordova Platforms : 6.0.0, android 7.1.4, browser, ios 5.1.1
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, cordova-plugin-ionic 5.4.7, (and 9 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.15.2
native-run  : 1.3.0

System:

(C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk)
NodeJS            : v10.7.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm               : 6.1.0
OS                : Windows 10

Comment: the issue mignt be that you're using a method that doesn't work for you. Have you tried all the methods of adding the paystack button as provided by angular4-paystack ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-paystack) and let us know. Also take a look on github, there's projects using it.